# How do I create a list with elements from 1 to N in prolog

Tags: prolog

I've tried to create a program that makes a list with elements from 1 to N.

```
increasing(L, N):-
   increasing(L, N, 1).

increasing([X|L], N, X):-
   X =< N,
   X1 is X + 1,
   increasing(L, N, X1).
```

But for some reason it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that eventually, you will make a call to `increasing/3` where `X <= N` is *not* satisfied, and then that predicate will fail, and thus "unwind" the entire call stack.

You thus need to make a predicate that will succeed if `X > N`, for example:

```
increasing(L, N):-
    increasing(L, N, 1).

increasing([], N, X) :-
    X > N,
    !.
increasing([X|L], N, X):-
    X =< N,
    X1 is X + 1,
    increasing(L, N, X1).
```

For example:

```
?- increasing(L, 5).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

Comment: And what about `increasing(L, 0)`?

Comment: @false: that sill set `L = []`, which makes sense, since there are no numbers from `1` to `0` in increasing order.